# Passing parameter to NewForm.aspx

Tags: url, parameter, newform

Does anyone know if its possible to pass a parameter from a list page to NewForm.aspx?

I have a list which is currently filtered on owners of tasks where users will be able to view the tasks currently assigned to them. If they click on a link to go to NewForm.aspx and they then fill out a new task and return to the task list, the filter is lost and they can now see all tasks.

Is it possible to pass a 'Source' parameter to NewForm.aspx so that when the user returns to the list it is again filtered only on their tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Change the default view of the list to the view of Assigned to = [Me].  This way no code is required.

If they are viewing the list on a different page other than the actual list page, then you can set a link to the NewForm.aspx and add `&Source=<url of page they were on>` to bring them back to the page they were previously on.

Comment: Jordan, thanks for the response. Is their anyway to do this without limiting users to only seeing their own tasks? Ideally I'd like anyone to be able to view others tasks and when returning from NewForm the list would be filtered the same way as it was originally.

Comment: Do you have these views existing already or do they need to be made?  If they are existing you can use the Source URL to point back to that view.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Rackleys linked lists post contains exactly that, and similar technics
http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=40